# Gravity forms convert date to Unix and add a year

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, unix, gravityforms

I'm trying to convert a date in WordPress Gravity Forms from dmy to Unix, which works fine by adding the below to functions.php but I want to add a +1 year to the converted date. Where am I going wrong?

```
  function rkv_datesubmit_fix2 ($form){
        //ACTUAL START DATE FIELD, date field id is 601 in gravity forms
        $raw_srt = $_POST['input_601'];
        $raw_end = $_POST['input_602'];

        // convert dates to unix
        $fix_srt = strtotime ($raw_srt);
        $fix_end = strtotime($raw_end);

            //output to gravity forms field 603 (start date)
            //output to gravity forms field 604 (end date)
        $_POST['input_603'] = $fix_srt;
        $_POST['input_604'] = $fix_end;
    }

add_action('gform_pre_submission', 'rkv_datesubmit_fix2');
```

If it change `$fix_srt = strtotime ($raw_srt);` to `strtotime('+ 1 year', $raw_srt);` I get 1971/1/1, not the original input date from Gravity field 601 plus a year.

Comment: Hi scamper. I made a lot of improvements to this post, so if you have further changes, please refresh your page and edit my copy, rather than restoring the old version. Thanks!

Comment: I went to answer to your question, when saw, that you changed your function. what is `$raw_end` there?

Comment: There is a line missing for $raw_end where this is the end date. It has the same function as raw_srt, adding 12 months to both the start and the end date fields.

Comment: it's a bit strange. that line need to be there, if you want to get help. or we can't provide you right answers. also, you want to add +1 year to `$fix_end`?

Comment: I’ve added the line in but I can’t wrap it in code for some reason.

Comment: you may want to look at [How to format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) . Also, please. let me know, where you want to add +1 year? to `$fix_end`?

Comment: Yes it is to fix_end

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code:

```
function rkv_datesubmit_fix2 ($form){
    //ACTUAL START DATE FIELD, date field id is 601 in gravity forms
    $raw_srt = $_POST['input_601'];
    $raw_end = $_POST['input_602'];

    // convert dates to unix
    $fix_srt = strtotime ($raw_srt);
    $fix_end = strtotime($raw_end.' + 1 year');

    //output to gravity forms field 603 (start date)
    //output to gravity forms field 604 (end date)
    $_POST['input_603'] = $fix_srt;
    $_POST['input_604'] = $fix_end;
}

add_action('gform_pre_submission', 'rkv_datesubmit_fix2');
```

For adding +1 year to `$fix_end` we just used `strtotime($raw_end.' + 1 year')`. This is simplest way to achieve the result you want.